# Excel Add-in not working in workbook with selection change event

Tags: vba, excel-2007, excel-addins

I am using MS Excel 2007 and have  a macro for highlighting selected cells rangs in yellow.
However, I want to make it work using Excel Add-In and be available for all of my workbooks.

What I have tried is save the Excel file as an Excel Add-In and Through  Excel Options activated it to be used.
But it  doesn't seem to work.

The code for highlighting:

```
[![Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        .Worksheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, , "TRUE"
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
End Sub][1]][1]
```

Do I need to set it up in a WorkBook_Open event to work.

Please help.

Comment: If you want that to work from an add-in then you will need to use Application Events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler

Comment: You can save it in your personal macro book and make a button: https://trumpexcel.com/personal-macro-workbook/